# How do I do a switch case with saving in the same array?

Tags: php, arrays

I need to save some numbers in my array. The numbers are the 
duration of how long the user was on my website.

like:

```
duration        quantity
0-30 sek        50
30sek-2min      100
....
```

So 50 user were about 0-30 sek on my webpage.

Now I have this array $visit_length with this output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3636
    [1] => 3637
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 40
    [4] => 9
)
```

This is the duration of how much secconds the user was on my website

Now I want to do a new array. Before this new array I need a foreach and an if/else or switch/case

like this:

```
$dauer_result = [];
        foreach ($visit_lenght as $lenght) {
            switch ($lenght) {
                case $lenght < 30:
                    $dauer_result = count($lenght);
                    continue;
                case $lenght > 30 and $lenght < 120:
                    $dauer_result = count($lenght);
                    continue;
                case $lenght > 120 and $lenght < 300:
                    $dauer_result = count($lenght);
                    continue;
                case $lenght > 300 and $lenght < 900:
                    $dauer_result = count($lenght);
                    continue;
                case $lenght > 900 and $lenght < 1800:
                    $dauer_result = count($lenght);
                    continue;
                case $lenght > 1800 and $lenght < 3600:
                    $dauer_result = count($lenght);
                    continue;
                case $lenght > 3600:
                    $dauer_result = count($lenght);
            }
        }
```

of course this says if $length is more than 'amount of secconds' than save the result of count($length) in the new array $dauer_length

for example: the first two keys of the $visit_length variable are 3636 and 3637

that means they are in the last case. so in $dauer_result should be written a two because both are higher than 3600.

Or maybe someone of you have another better way. 
Well I hope you understood what I'm trying to say.. My english isn't the best..

Thanks for your help :)

--------------------- UPDATE: -------------------

Solved Code:

```
$dauer_result = array('<30'=>0, '30-120'=>0, '120-300'=>0, '300-900'=>0, '900-1800'=>0, '1800-3600'=>0, '>3600'=>0);
        foreach ($visit_lenght as $lenght) {
            switch ($lenght) {
                case $lenght < 30:
                    $dauer_result['<30'] +=1 ;
                    continue;
                case $lenght > 30 and $lenght < 120:
                    $dauer_result['30-120'] +=1 ;
                    continue;
                case $lenght > 120 and $lenght < 300:
                    $dauer_result['120-300'] +=1 ;
                    continue;
                case $lenght > 300 and $lenght < 900:
                    $dauer_result['300-900'] +=1 ;
                    continue;
                case $lenght > 900 and $lenght < 1800:
                    $dauer_result['900-1800'] +=1 ;
                    continue;
                case $lenght > 1800 and $lenght < 3600:
                    $dauer_result['1800-3600'] +=1 ;
                    continue;
                case $lenght 3600:
                    $dauer_result['>3600'] +=1 ;
                    continue;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for

```
$dauer_result = array('<30'=>0, '30-120'=>0, '120-300'=>0, '300-900'=>0, '900-1800'=>0, '1800-3600'=>0, '>3600'=>0);
        foreach ($visit_lenght as $lenght) {
            switch ($lenght) {
                case $lenght < 30:
                    $dauer_result['<30'] +=1 ;
                    continue;
                case $lenght > 30 and $lenght < 120:
                    $dauer_result['30-120'] +=1 ;
                    continue;
                case $lenght > 120 and $lenght < 300:
                    $dauer_result['120-300'] +=1 ;
                    continue;
                case $lenght > 300 and $lenght < 900:
                    $dauer_result['300-900'] +=1 ;
                    continue;
                case $lenght > 900 and $lenght < 1800:
                    $dauer_result['900-1800'] +=1 ;
                    continue;
                case $lenght > 1800 and $lenght < 3600:
                    $dauer_result['1800-3600'] +=1 ;
                    continue;
                case $lenght 3600:
                    $dauer_result['>3600'] +=1 ;
                    continue;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be done by using `array_filter` which uses a custom function to filter the values from your array. An example is below:

```
$visit_length = array(3636, 3637, 3, 40, 9 );

function length_filter($var)
{
    return ($var > 3600);
}

$result = array_filter($visit_length, 'length_filter');
```

The variable `$result` now holds an array which only contains values which are higher then `3600`.

Comment: well and if I need this for many cases? like between 0-30 seconds, 30-60seconds .... ?

Comment: Oh I just reread your question now and now I get it. You should simply reverse the order of your switch cases. Just put your `case $lenght > 3600:` case first.

Comment: I thought maybe I can use some indexes in my array. Like $dauer_result['0.30'] = 2 --- $dauer_result['30-60'] = 0 ... or something like this

Comment: Reverse the order of your cases in your switch case. You are also overwriting your `$dauer_result` for each value in `visit_lenght`. I suspect your `$dauer_result` variable will be an integer at the end of your script. Instead use: `$dauer_result[] = count($lenght);` to push your value to the end of your array.

Comment: okay I did that - I will update my quesion with the result and code. Check my question in about a minute

Comment: okay the answer under this one helped me perfectly, thanks anyway :)